# Specific search pattern using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to search for a pattern in following type of strings.

I have both of these patterns

```
"<deliveries!ntg5!intel!api!ntg5!avt!tuner!src>CDAVTTunerTVProxy.cpp"
```

and

```
"<.>api/sys/mocca/pf/comm/component/src\HBServices.hpp"
```

I would like to extract the file names from the patterns above

I tried the following

```
if(m/(\|>[0-9a-zA-Z_]\.cpp"$|\.hpp"$|\.h"$|\.c")$/){
```

Above expression is not listing file names with  `" >xxxxx.cpp"` ( or .hpp, or .h, or .c)

Any idea would be of great help.

Comment: I corrected other patterh, instead of only .cpp file following is the pattern

Comment: I suspect you would probably like `\w` instead of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Also, perhaps you would be interested in the module [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ABasename) which will allow you to extract file names from paths. It is a core module in Perl 5.

Comment: Is `\|>` meant to be "match backslash OR >"? Because you have to escape backslash in that case. And you have to group that alternation to separate it from the following one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your regex

```
if(m/(\|>[0-9a-zA-Z_]\.cpp"$|\.hpp"$|\.h"$|\.c")$/){
```

I assume that `\|>` is supposed to match either `\` or `>`, but this is incorrect. It will try to match a pipe `|` followed by `>`. Backslash is used to escape characters, and so if you want to match a literal backslash, you need to escape it: `\\`. This is the wrong way to use an alternation, though (see more below), and there is a better way, which is to use a character class: `[\\>]`.

`[0-9a-zA-Z_]` is a character class that is represented by `\w`, so it makes sense to use that instead to make your regex more readable. Also, you are only matching one character. If you want to match more than that, you need to supply a quantifier, such as `+`, which is suitable in this case. The quantifier `+` means to match 1 or more times.

Your alternations `|` are mixed up. Unless you group them properly, they will be intended to match the entire string. Your regex as it is now would capture strings like:

```
|>A.cpp"
.hpp"
.c"
```

Which is not what you want. If you want to apply the different extensions to the main file name body, you have to group the alternate extensions properly:

```
\w+\.(?:cpp|hpp|h|c)"$
```

Using parentheses that do not capture `(?: ... )` are suitable for grouping. As you can also see, there is no need to repeat the parts of the string which are identical for all extensions.

So what do we end up with?

```
/([\\>]\w+\.(?:cpp|hpp|h|c)")$/
```

Although I do not think that you *really* want to include the leading `[\\>]` in the match, or the trailing `"`. So more properly it would be

```
/[\\>](\w+\.(?:cpp|hpp|h|c))"$/
```

Note that as I said in the comment, there is a module to use if these are paths, and you want to extract the file name. [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename) is included in Perl core since version 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot TLP, /[\\>](\w+\.(?:cpp|hpp|h|c))"$/ worked great.

Comment: Regarding File::Basename, actually there are about 10-20 patterns which are difficult to parse, some times they have ! in between directories, some times there is a base path, and after that there is one path series of path with with file name. Hence I am thinking to get the file name, and in other text file get list of file names with complete path. Then search each file name in this text file to get complete path of parsed list of files. Hope this makes sense, if any better way let me know

Comment: Is there any better way to get full path of a file, if file name and base directory is given. I mean to say if C:\foo\bar\ , c:\foo\bar\foobar\ directory and aaaa.cpp, bbbb.hpp, cccc.h file name has to be searched in above directories to get full path, i know file exists in any of directries, but full path has to be generated with out consuming much of CPU time.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking there, and if you have another question, it is better to post it as a new one and not use comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex:

```
m/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+\.(?:cpp|hpp|h|c))$/
```

This one is looking for the extension cpp, hpp, h or c at the end of the string(using `$`) and then looking for the file name just before the period(`.`) with extension.